# Access the JVM section of elasticsearch through the monitoring API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

How I can access the jvm section of the node stats API ?

I've read about it in the docs - [monitoring individual nodes](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_monitoring_individual_nodes.html)

I'm doing a call to

```
/_nodes/stats?pretty=true
```

but don't have the jvm section here.

Instead I have this:

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "foobarbaz",
  "nodes" : {
    "Avlpu1rJSHq4168HrMC5ZQ" : {
      "timestamp" : 1419232511049,
      "name" : "ves09",
      "transport_address" : "inet[/192.168.32.27:9300]",
      "hostname" : "ves09",
      "indices" : {
        "docs" : {
          "count" : 6540067,
          "deleted" : 0
        },
        "store" : {
          "size" : "7.7gb",
          "size_in_bytes" : 8293747163,
          "throttle_time" : "20.4m",
          "throttle_time_in_millis" : 1227493
        },
        "indexing" : {
          "index_total" : 4905059,
          "index_time" : "33.7m",
          "index_time_in_millis" : 2026968,
          "index_current" : 0,
          "delete_total" : 0,
          "delete_time" : "0s",
          "delete_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "delete_current" : 0
        },
        "get" : {
          "total" : 0,
          "get_time" : "0s",
          "time_in_millis" : 0,
          "exists_total" : 0,
          "exists_time" : "0s",
          "exists_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "missing_total" : 0,
          "missing_time" : "0s",
          "missing_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "current" : 0
        },
        "search" : {
          "open_contexts" : 0,
          "query_total" : 27335627,
          "query_time" : "1.5d",
          "query_time_in_millis" : 137058047,
          "query_current" : 0,
          "fetch_total" : 8774008,
          "fetch_time" : "9.9h",
          "fetch_time_in_millis" : 35957388,
          "fetch_current" : 0
        }
      }
    },
    "dcGrstVDScalZ6QyyAr7nw" : {
      "timestamp" : 1419232511036,
      "name" : "ves08",
      "transport_address" : "inet[/192.168.32.24:9300]",
      "hostname" : "ves08",
      "indices" : {
        "docs" : {
          "count" : 6540067,
          "deleted" : 0
        },
        "store" : {
          "size" : "7.7gb",
          "size_in_bytes" : 8292131741,
          "throttle_time" : "22.8m",
          "throttle_time_in_millis" : 1370025
        },
        "indexing" : {
          "index_total" : 4905059,
          "index_time" : "29.3m",
          "index_time_in_millis" : 1763623,
          "index_current" : 0,
          "delete_total" : 0,
          "delete_time" : "0s",
          "delete_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "delete_current" : 0
        },
        "get" : {
          "total" : 0,
          "get_time" : "0s",
          "time_in_millis" : 0,
          "exists_total" : 0,
          "exists_time" : "0s",
          "exists_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "missing_total" : 0,
          "missing_time" : "0s",
          "missing_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "current" : 0
        },
        "search" : {
          "open_contexts" : 0,
          "query_total" : 27403482,
          "query_time" : "1d",
          "query_time_in_millis" : 93573983,
          "query_current" : 0,
          "fetch_total" : 8789753,
          "fetch_time" : "6.5h",
          "fetch_time_in_millis" : 23516893,
          "fetch_current" : 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**How I can access the JVM section through the API ?**

Answer (score 0):

What shows the following output

```
_nodes/stats/jvm?pretty=true
```

[Documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-stats.html)

Maybe you have an older version. Try this

```
_cluster/stats?human&pretty
```